# Demystifying a JQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, lambda

I'm trying to get into Javascript Lambda approach but I'm still very confused by the very flexible way stuff can be defined and variables scope.

For example I'm looking into the code of the following plugin, beside there are other part of the code that are not clear to me, I'm interested in how the code is organized.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Cloud Zoom V1.0.2
// (c) 2010 by R Cecco. <http://www.professorcloud.com>
// MIT License
//
// Please retain this copyright header in all versions of the software
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
(function ($) {

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.cloud-zoom, .cloud-zoom-gallery').CloudZoom();
    });

    function CloudZoom(jWin, opts) {
     ....
    }

    $.fn.CloudZoom = function (options) {
    ....
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Now I suppose `$` and `$.fn` are 2 objects defined by jQuery and they are used in order to create a separate namespace/scope for the plugin code an their variables

I would like to have some light on the following points:

1. `(function($){})(jQuery)` what does it means ? `function($)` looks to me an anonymous (lambda) function that takes as parameter `$` but I'm not sure the meaning of the last `(jQuery)` stuff.
2. The internal function `function CloudZoom(jWin, opts)` should be available only in the internal scope right ?
3. `$.fn.CloudZoom` is 'extending' the `$.fn` object ... any reason why they have the same name with the above function ?
4. the code `$('.cloud-zoom, .cloud-zoom-gallery').CloudZoom();` is actually calling which function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 `function($){})(jQuery) etc` is an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) and simply provides a locally scoped `$` variable for `jQuery` to avoid clashes of `$` with other plugins. Yes, it is just an anonymous function that is called immediately to provide scope for other declarations.

An IIFE is basically calling an anonymous function like this one (it has no name):

```
function(){}
```

wrapped in parenthesis to make it referenceable:

```
(function(){})
```

so you can do this to run it immediately:

```
(function(){})();
```

You can of course pass parameters to it as well:

```
(function(param1, param2){
     // param1 = 1
     // param2 = 2
})(1,2);
```

So their example is doing this:

```
(function($){
    // $ is now the same as jQuery!
})(jQuery);
```

2. Yes. That function should only be available within the scope of the outer function.
3. None I can think of. The naming can be anything so long as it does not clash. (I usually use `ProperCase` for the class-function and `pascalCase` for the .fn extension).
4. `$('.cloud-zoom, .cloud-zoom-gallery').CloudZoom()` calls the following function with `this` being the jQuery object/collection returned from `$('.cloud-zoom, .cloud-zoom-gallery')`:

---

```
$.fn.CloudZoom = function (options) {
....
     var $thisIsTheSelectorResult = this; // == $('.cloud-zoom, .cloud-zoom-gallery')
};
```

Comment: Lol, that's very straight forward, tho I think he means a bit more explanation. Think I might blog a beginner jquery this weekend. did once long ago and never really finished it. it's time.

Comment: @ SpYk3HH: Let me finish first :)

Comment: Within the plugin, `this` is already a jQuery object - no need for another `$()` wrap.

Comment: lol, go ahead, i see the updates! lol, i c wut u did thar! good timing, plus 1!

Comment: Thanks you very much, I almost got it ... together with an headache :)
Can you add some more details on point 1 ?

Comment: @lnitak: Yes, thanks got that. Bad habit from typing 1000s of callbacks with $(this) :)

Comment: I would also (selflessly, i might add \*sarcastic font\*) like to add this link to this question i put up for discussion on Code Review about a very simply jQuery Plugin layout to follow regularly. I've since had to make some changes for "hardcore" plugs, but not enough to change this as a "recomended basic layout" with FULL explanation to all the `moving parts`. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18809/what-could-make-this-jquery-plugin-template-nicer :-P

Comment: @SpYk3HH: Interesting link. For my own plugins I work in TypeScript (to make very large projects easier) and inherit a base plugin class to do most of the heavy lifting for my 20+ plugins. I got sick of seeing the same code repeated over and over on every plugin :) I gather the jQuery plugin extension lib does something similar.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Yeah, that's the whole reason I came up with that layout and why i posted it on code review. Partially was to get others input (which i've received little of), but mostly i posted it there so i can easily go there from any PC and CnP the layout and start writing whatever Plugin I need. I also have a full lib of plugins at my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/Q2R7P/) ... that sight ever goes down, i be so sad ... luckily i smart enough to copy my own jsFiddle once every 90 days or so, lol.

Comment: @SpYk3HH your "disinterestedness" is welcome, since it is something that was in my mind to ask in my question, something like "is this pattern recommended ?"

Comment: @WonderLand: Is that enough for point 1, or do you need any details clarified?

Comment: I gave both Q and A point, this is all good. Anything that helps nubs to jQuery, i'm all for! More people need to jump on jQ. I hopped on a few years ago ... now i try to forget Vanilla JS. like for real, i just wanna never remember that nightmare ... and oh the nightmare of writing Prototype methods, or MooTools extesnions! ARGH! THANK YOU JQUERY!!!

Comment: ok got it so the `(jQuery)` is basically a parameter for the anonymous function.
Thanks you are healing my headache :) 
Double thanks for the fast response

Comment: @SpYk3HH I agree anyway you need to dig in "vanilla js" to fully understand jQuery: without Douglas Crockford stuff I could not understand TrueBlueAussie answer ...